# How can I initialise a Cap12xxInputDriver with AndroidThings?

Tags: android-things

I have cloned the androidthings example for capacitive touch at:
https://github.com/androidthings/drivers-samples/tree/master/cap12xx

The following is used to initialise the driver:

```
mInputDriver = new Cap12xxInputDriver(this, BoardDefaults.getI2CPort(), null,Cap12xx.Configuration.CAP1208,keyCodes);
```

When this gets hit I get an exception as below. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix this as I can't see what happens in the I2cDevice class. The hardware setup is a RainbowHAT mounted in a Raspberry Pi Model 3 B. The display, temperature, pressure and LEDs work fine.

How can I initialise a Cap12xxInputDriver?

```
04-29 20:33:45.159 1238-1238/? W/CaptouchActivity: Unable to open driver connection
com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error
at com.google.android.things.pio.I2cDevice.writeRegByte(I2cDevice.java:198)
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xx.setInputsEnabled(Cap12xx.java:418)
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xx.init(Cap12xx.java:241)
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xx.<init>(Cap12xx.java:188)
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xxInputDriver.<init>(Cap12xxInputDriver.java:92)
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xxInputDriver.<init>(Cap12xxInputDriver.java:69)
at com.example.androidthings.driversamples.CaptouchActivity.onCreate(CaptouchActivity.java:51)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1697)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
at com.google.android.things.pio.IPeripheralManagerClient$Stub$Proxy.I2cWriteRegByte(IPeripheralManagerClient.java:1517)
at com.google.android.things.pio.I2cDevice.writeRegByte(I2cDevice.java:196)
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xx.setInputsEnabled(Cap12xx.java:418) 
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xx.init(Cap12xx.java:241) 
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xx.<init>(Cap12xx.java:188) 
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xxInputDriver.<init>(Cap12xxInputDriver.java:92) 
at com.google.android.things.contrib.driver.cap12xx.Cap12xxInputDriver.<init>(Cap12xxInputDriver.java:69) 
at com.example.androidthings.driversamples.CaptouchActivity.onCreate(CaptouchActivity.java:51) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CAP1208 chip on the [Rainbow HAT](https://github.com/pimoroni/rainbow-hat/blob/master/documentation/Technical-reference.md), so attempting to initialize one on the I2C bus is throwing an error when it begins to write init commands since the device is not there. The capacitive buttons on the Rainbow HAT are managed internally and exposed as pure GPIO pins.

If you want to experiment with the cap touch features of the CAP12xx family, you could try the [Explorer HAT Pro](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/explorer-hat) for the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

Like Devunwired said the Rainbow HAT capacitive buttons are exposed via GPIO. They're very easy to use.

You can find the pin numbers here: [Technical Reference - 3 Touch Inputs via AT42QT1070](https://github.com/pimoroni/rainbow-hat/blob/master/documentation/Technical-reference.md)

How to use the touch buttons here: https://github.com/blundell/androidthings-gpio-input

Here is an example of using Capacitive Button A on the Rainbow Hat in an Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TOUCH_BUTTON_A_PIN = "BCM21";

    private Gpio bus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PeripheralManager service = PeripheralManager.newInstance();

        try {
            bus = service.openGpio(TOUCH_BUTTON_A_PIN);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(TOUCH_BUTTON_A_PIN + " bus cannot be opened.", e);
        }

        try {
            bus.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_IN);
            bus.setActiveType(Gpio.ACTIVE_LOW);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(TOUCH_BUTTON_A_PIN + " bus cannot be configured.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            bus.setEdgeTriggerType(Gpio.EDGE_BOTH);
            bus.registerGpioCallback(touchButtonACallback);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(TOUCH_BUTTON_A_PIN + " bus cannot be monitored.", e);
        }
    }

    private final GpioCallback touchButtonACallback = new GpioCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGpioEdge(Gpio gpio) {
            try {
                if (gpio.getValue()) {
                    Log.i("TUT", "ON PRESSED DOWN");
                } else {
                    Log.i("TUT", "ON PRESSED UP");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(TOUCH_BUTTON_A_PIN + " cannot be read.", e);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        bus.unregisterGpioCallback(touchButtonACallback);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            bus.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TUT", TOUCH_BUTTON_A_PIN + " bus cannot be closed, you may experience errors on next launch.", e);
        }
    }
}
```